# How can you assign a var to a function and duplicate it?

Tags: javascript

Since the assignment operator can essentially assign variables to values/objects why cant you assign a variable to a function.

For example: When I assign var b = 5; b turns into 5, same for Objects when I create an instance. var b = c;

However when I assign var b = func(); it gives me the result or the return. Why does it do this and how do you make a duplicate function without the use of a closure or factory?

Comment: Uh... `var b = func;`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `()` characters are the syntax that means "call the function".

Remove them and you'll get the reference to the function object instead of calling it and getting the return value.

```
function func () {
    alert(1);
}

var b = func;
b();
setTimeout(func, 2000);
```